# Meaning of "every dewdrop paints a bow" from In Memoriam, Section CXXII by Alfred lord Tennyson

Tags: meaning, poetry, alfred-tennyson

> And every dewdrop paints a bow

A line by Alfred Lord Tennyson, from section CXXII of his poem [*In Memoriam*](http://www.online-literature.com/tennyson/718/). What is the poet actually trying to convey with this line?

The verse in context:

> And all the breeze of Fancy blows,
>   And every dew-drop paints a bow,
>   The wizard lightnings deeply glow,
>   And every thought breaks out a rose.

Answer (score 11):

The reference is to the properties of water refracting the light spectrum, effectively producing a *rainbow*.

The OED bears this out with the following definition of 'Bow'.:

> II. Specific uses.
>
> 2. A rainbow. (Mostly contextual or poetical for the compound.)

In fact the OED specifically cites this line as an example of this usage:

> 1850   Tennyson *In Memoriam* cxx. 189    Every dew-drop paints a bow .

I think the speaker is essentially saying that if his love were still with him he would never think of death but instead of flights of fancy, all rainbows, magic and roses.